# how to import another intellij module and its dependencies to my module classpath?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have module A which dependent on module B.

I want to import module B and its dependencies into module A.

I have tried to do it via `project info`:

[image]

[image]

But i have a problem that some of module B external dependencies are not imported to module A to be used.

How can i fix this?

Comment: In a Gradle based project all the dependencies should be defined via `build.gradle`, otherwise the manual changes to the module structure will be discarded on the next Gradle project refresh. Consider using gradle composite builds feature or multiprojects.

Comment: I removed it from the `gradle.build` but it didn't change.

Comment: As far as I see, you need to define a composite build of multiple projects and import it in IntelliJ IDEA: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/.